# Appending to a nested dictionary with custom class

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

I am using python 3.7. I am running some analysis on the RSSI values obtained from wireshark and therefore need to plot the various RSSI values with respect to a channel.
I have created the following classes to hold different attributes such as mean(list), median, mode, std dev etc.
While parsing through the individual data files I plan to go about and collect the data in the above lists for each channel.
To be able to plot these values I need to pass the attributes as a list to the plot function. I am having trouble designing/defining  the data structures.

```
ch_rssiattr_list = collections.defaultdict(lambda : collections.defaultdict(list))
ch_rssiattr_list[channel]['mean'].append(mean)
```

The above method would be acceptable - not a class instantiation method.

A more elegant way I could think was creating a class with the various attributes as I was explaining above as I am parsing the data through various distances.
In C++ I would create a map with the key as a channel and value as a class object.
As I am parsing through the data. I almost need a way to update the values in the following way.

```
ch_rssiattr_list[channel].mean_list.append(mean)
```

I do not know how to declare this data structure.

Any other design/ implementation methods are welcome as well but the above two ways seem simple enough to me so the right way to declare data structures here would be helpful to know. Hopefully I explained my question well enough, a google search on nested dictionaries and lists did not exactly give me what I was looking for although I do understand how nested dictionaries and lists can be declared, but in general how would you declare them for your custom class seems a bit confusing to me.

Here is what my custom class looks like.

```
class summary_lists(object):
    def __init__(self,dist_list, mean_list, median_list, mode_list,
                std_dev_list, mmode_list, unique_count_list, total_datapoint_list,
                min_list, max_list):

        self.dist_list = dist_list   
        self.mean_list = mean_list
        self.mode_list = mode_list
        self.median_list = median_list
        self.std_dev_list = std_dev_list
        self.mmode_list = mmode_list
        self.unique_count_list = unique_count_list
        self.total_datapoint_list = total_datapoint_list
        self.min_list = min_list
```

Comment: What doesn't work with the approaches you've outlined? Slight improvement to your class approach could be to use [@dataclass](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/dataclasses.html#dataclasses.dataclass). And you might want a way to initialize the class without giving it any initial data (`self, mean_list=None, ...; if mean_list is None: self.mean_list = []; ...`).

Comment: Update, after some debugging efforts, found that the first method works. I was getting a Type name error. I tracked it to some other error. I am still confused as to how the second method can be instantiated. But it helped me make progress, that might be good enough for now. Thanks ! Data classes are interesting, I will explore them more.